# How to stop from view being rendered while sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.0.9 and I have following code to send an email when a comment is posted.

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def comment_notification(comment)
    User.active.each do |user|
      @user = user
      mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => subject)
    end
  end

end
```

If there are not active users then User.active is empty and the code inside does not get executed. However the view is rendered and view fails because @user is missing.

The above code is invoked by observer

```
Mailer.comment_notification(comment).deliver
```

One way to fix this problem would be to change the code in observer to something like this

```
User.active.each do |recipient|
  Mailer.comment_notification(comment, recipient).deliver
end
```

Is this the right way to fix this way. I would like my observer to be as thin as possible.

Comment: Does that actually work, sending multiple emails from one mailer method?  The `#mail` method returns the actual `Mail` object, on which you then call `#deliver`.  I think the problem here is that you don't return a `Mail` object, but then call `#deliver` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your observer fix is correct. You should loop through and send emails one by one. The mailer should just send one email at a time. This is a job best left to Delayed Job though. You don't want to waiting around while an email sends.

Here is a tutorial on Delayed Job: http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

Be sure to check the Readme for Delayed Job as well, paying special attention to the "Rails 3 Mailers" section: http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job